# different map with mapCountryData?

Tags: r, maps, rworldmap

with the code below, using mapCountryData function I'm able to generate nice map with some countries painted in red:

```
> d <- data.frame(country=c("Greece", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Norway", "Spain", "Netherlands"), value=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
> n <- joinCountryData2Map(d, joinCode="NAME", nameJoinColumn="country")
> mapCountryData(n, nameColumnToPlot = "value", catMethod = "categorical", mapRegion="Europe", oceanCol = "white", missingCountryCol="light grey", borderCol = "white")
```

[map generated with mapCountryData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxo7F.jpg)

The only thing that I want to change is the map resolution, to have something like below, generated through simple get_map function:

```
> newmap <- getMap(resolution="low")
> plot(newmap, xlim = c(-20, 59), ylim = c(35, 71), asp = 1)
```

[map generated with getMap()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkI0R.png)

The second map, not colored, is more detailed (shore line, borders, islands etc) and I'd like to use this map instead of generic one from mapCountryData.

Is it possible to use it with mapCountryData?
If not, if it possible to color it somehow? Maybe a link? I did some research but all available tutorials/manuals online seems to use the first one, generic map.

thanks in advance